# tor bundle : how to launch or run the core tor alone without the browser?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

If running the Tor browser (formerly known as the bundle), is it possible to shut down (close) the browser app while keeping the core Tor (established circuits, proxy port...) active?

Assume Linux for specificity.

Alternatively, please outline instructions for launching the core tor (from the Linux bundle) without an instance of the bundled browser.

Then, instructions for orderly closing tor and any dependencies after use.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Tor Browser comes with a copy of `tor` included. So just run, `cd tor-browser_en-US/Browser/`, from whichever location you extracted Tor Browser to, then run `./TorBrowser/Tor/tor` and to use the tor browser configuration files add `-f ./TorBrowser/Data/Tor/torrc --defaults-torrc ./TorBrowser/Data/Tor/torrc-defaults`

However this is a bad idea in all cases, and for use as a standalone daemon there are better solutions readily available for most Linux distributions by installing Tor through the package manager.